# How to call user function for multiple array values in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the full code try it and tell me why value of $b is not incrementing in the following line

```
call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a, &$b));
```

of the following code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function increment(&$var) {
    $var++;
}

$a = 0;
echo "$a<br>";
call_user_func('increment', &$a); 
echo "$a<br>";
$b = 0;
call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a, &$b));
echo "$a.$b<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how `call_user_func_array` works.

```
call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a, &$b));
```

executes

```
increment($a, $b);
```

not

```
increment($a);
increment($b);
```

If you want the second option, try `array_map`.

Comment: okay ! nice this will work. I know array map, but i was learning call_user_func, Thanks U made me know

Comment: buddy can we use array_walk instead of array_map